# Finding the IE version in Windows Server 2008

Tags: internet-explorer-9, windows-server-2008

I have IE9 installed in Windows Server 2008 64bit and am trying to find the IE version to support HTML5 using the user agent string but the user agent string thrown does not say, anything about IE9 installed there:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
>     Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;     .NET
>   CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Trying the same is Windows 7, gives more info:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;    Trident/5.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;    .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
>   Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C;    .NET4.0E; BOIE9;ENUS)

so how can I find the IE version installed in Windows Server 2008 64-bit?
Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: Do you need to sniff the query string? A feature-detection library like Modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/) might be able to meet your needs in a more robust fashion.

Comment: Nope, I want to do it using simple java script; this user agent string works in Windows 7; just that not working in Windows Server 2008

Comment: One of the huge problems with browser fingerprinting is that browser UA strings vary greatly from one platform to the next. As you're seeing, IE9 is throwing up a different string depending on the OS it's installed on. If you're strictly worried about IE9, another possibility might be to use a browser conditional tag (see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 0):

This particular [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck.shtml) helped me to overcome the issue of finding the IE version supporting HTML5. (look for section : Checking for support for the canvas element of HTML 5)